# Launching Task on Spring Cloud Dataflow Server on Kubernetes / OpenShift Fails

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've installed Spring Cloud Dataflow on OpenShift / Kubernetes using bitnami helm chart.
On OpenShift, you have to disable security contexts in custom values in order to deploy and run SCDF services.

```yaml
  podSecurityContext:
    enabled: false
  containerSecurityContext:
    enabled: false
```

Otherwise OpenShift reports an error:

```
provider "restricted-loki": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount,
provider restricted: .spec.securityContext.fsGroup: 
Invalid value: []int64{1001}: 1001 is not an allowed group, spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: 
Invalid value: 1001: must be in the ranges: [1001230000, 1001239999]
```

After disabling security contexts, the deployment works fine. However, when I register an application (task via docker-URL) and try to launch it, I get a similar error:

```
Failure executing: POST at: https://172.29.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/my-ns/pods. 
Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. 
pods "my-task-8jm653e6rp" is forbidden: unable to validate against any security context constraint: 
[
provider "anyuid": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, 
provider "mtc-minio": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, 
provider "restricted-loki": Forbidden: not usable by user or serviceaccount, 
spec.containers[0].securityContext.runAsUser: Invalid value: 1001: must be in the ranges: [1001230000, 1001239999],
...
```

So I assume that it is again a security context issue. Is there a way to pass kubernetes deployment properties to disable security contexts?

I tried setting the deployment property `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.pod-security-context.run-as-user=1001230001` but the error remains the same.

Or am I on the wrong track? What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set deployer / Deployment Platform property:

```
deployer.my-task.kubernetes.podSecurityContext={runAsUser: 1001230000}
```

as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_pod_security_context

Setting the value in the UI results in a different property (`deployer.my-task.kubernetes.pod-security-context.run-as-user=1001230000`) that does not seem to work. Might be a bug in Spring Cloud Data Flow?